# Memory Game hack(not wanted) to double click same card and make a match

Tags: javascript

I am trying to not allow a match to be called if the user clicks on the same card in the memory game. It is still allowing that though

I've tried tracking the mouse and trying to not let it click the same card.

```
<script>

var OpenCard = [];

if (OpenCard.length == 2){
    const CardType1 = 
    OpenCard[0].querySelector('i').classList.item(1)
    const CardType2 = 
    OpenCard[1].querySelector('i').classList.item(1)
    console.log(CardType1, CardType2);
    movespassed();
    check_stars();

    //compares two cards and checks for a match
    if (CardType1 == CardType2){
        OpenCard.forEach(function(card){ 
            card.classList.add('match')
        });
        OpenCard = []
        game_score++;
        console.log(game_score);



    }
    //if cards don't match close them
    else{
        console.log("i'm here")
        setTimeout(function(){
            OpenCard.forEach(function(card){ 
                card.classList.remove('show', 'open')
            })
            OpenCard = []
        },200);
    }
</script>function(c){
            OpenCard.push(card);
            track.push(card);
            card.classList.add('show', 'open');
```

Comment: Your code is somewhat confusing. What is `OpenCard`? It appears to be an array of elements. Give your elements unique ids and you can compare the id of one card to the other card and if they're the same, they've clicked on the same card. Hard to tell without the HTML. You might want to create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) that reproduces the issue you're having.

Comment: Open Card is basically a blank array. it equals to =[] just that

Comment: and i am pushing cards into that array

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that creates `OpenCard` and populates it with elements.

Comment: I did that now.

Comment: Your `if` block will never be true. The `OpenCard` variable's `length` is always 0.

Comment: No, when you click on 2 cards that are the same the OpenCard.length is 2

Comment: Look at the code you've shown here. The first line defines `OpenCard` as an empty array. The very next line of code compares the length of this empty array to see if it's 2. There must be code between those two lines of code that is missing from the question. That is what the question needs to have to be answerable.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I added them at the bottom since my computer wasn't working with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I need to see the actual element the user is clicking on to better answer this, but as a general rule, I like to use "flag" classes that are added to an element and then removed when needed.

For example:

```
function cardClick(element){
  if (!element.classList.contains('clicked')){
   element.classList.add('clicked');
  // The rest of your code goes here
   }
}
```

Then when the card is flipped back around, deleted, etc., use this to remove the "clicked" class:

```
element.classList.remove('clicked');
```

With the above, it'll only allow the first click because the second click will see that the "clicked" class is on the element and will bypass the rest of the code.